# Solidity dynamic unicode variable

Tags: solidity, string, constructor

I [previously](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97173/do-solidity-smart-contract-symbols-support-unicode) asked about unicode in Solidity and got some great answers (thanks for that!).

Issue is now I'm experimenting with passing in the value of a utf-8 (not a literal):

```js
    constructor (string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        _name = unicode(name_);
        _symbol = unicode(symbol_);
```

and this errors:

```sh
   |
   |         _name = unicode(name_);
   |                 ^^^^^^^
   |
   |         _symbol = unicode(symbol_);
   |                   ^^^^^^^
```

I couldn't find any resources about this, wondering if anyone has a solution or suggestion

Comment: Pass your strings as UTF-8 in transaction to your smart contract.

Answer (score 1):

'unicode' isnt a default keyword in solidity, if you want a function that converts utf8 to unicode, you'd have to implement it yourself.